# por que no se pinta mi rectangulo en java?

Tags: java

esta es mi clase metodo main:

```
public class dibujo3D{
public static void main (String[]args){
FrameConDibujos FCD = new FrameConDibujos();
FCD.paintComponent(null);
//FCD.setJF1();
} 
}
```

y esta es mi clase con constructor donde creo 1 panel, 1 frame y no se pinta el rectangulo

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class FrameConDibujos extends JPanel{
public FrameConDibujos(){
JFrame JF1 = new JFrame();       
JF1.setLayout(null);
JF1.setTitle("JF1");
JF1.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
Toolkit TK1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension TAMPANT = new Dimension();
TAMPANT =TK1.getScreenSize();
int Alto;
int Ancho;
Alto =TAMPANT.height;
Ancho = TAMPANT.width;
JF1.setSize((Alto/2),(Ancho/2));
JF1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
JF1.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
JF1.setVisible(true);
JPanel JP1 = new JPanel();  
JP1.setLayout(null);
JP1.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 200);//por que demonios se ignora esto?
JP1.setBackground(Color.red);
JP1.setVisible(true);
JF1.add(JP1);
}
@Override
public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
super.paintComponent(g);
g.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El rectangulo no se dibuja porque la sobre-escritura `paintComponent()` de `FrameConDibujos` jamas es llamada, por lo tanto es totalmente incorrecto cuando pones la instrucción `FCD.paintComponent(null);` en el `main`.

Puede arreglarse, simplemente especificando el contenedor del frame:

```
//Constructor FrameConDibujos
//...
JF1.setContentPane(this);
JF1.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
//...
```

Con esto, mediante `this` le hemos ordenado que el panel contenedor es `FrameConDibujos` -(*preferiría un nombre distinto para evitar confusiones*)-, dicho panel es el que trae el `paintComponent()` con el `drawRect()` que necesitas poner en pantalla.

Solo hay un pequeño detalle, con un `drawRect(100,100,100,100)`; no lo podrías ver porque quedaría detrás y totalmente tapado por el panel de color rojo.

Modifiqué entonces por un `drawRect(50,50,200,200);` y me mostró un resultado similar a este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]